# How do you listen for a keyUp event in Dart?

Tags: dart

How do I listen or register for the keyUp event on a DOM element in Dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that this thread is slightly out-of-date. In the latest version of Dart, you can listen to key up events like this:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  querySelector('#some-element').onKeyUp.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
    print(e.keyCode);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the keyUp you need to:

```
  query('#anElement').on.keyUp.add((Event e) {

  });
```

If you want the equivalent to:

```
$(".multipleElements").keyUp(function(){....});
```

Then you must do:

```
query('.multipleElements').forEach((key, value){
    value.on.keyUp.add((Event e) {

    }
});
```

If you want to know which element was triggered then you need to cast the target to an element:

```
query('.multipleElements').forEach((key, value){
    value.on.keyUp.add((Event e) {
        Element target = e.currentTarget;
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that this answer is now deprecated.  Streams are now returned, not things to add handlers to.